# Number of rows in UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

I have UITableView with custom cells, which contain  uilabels. 
I am using it to show comments and it must have flexible height.
How can I do it?
I have code, which counting number of rows with help of uilabel.text length, but it is wrong way. Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UILabel with numberOfLines set to zero.

Then, for making sure that your label actually fits into the cell, get the dimensions from the NSString UIKit extension like this;

```
CGFloat cellWidth = 320.0f; //example width....
labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cellWidth, FLT_MAX)];
```

From the NSString reference;
sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:

> Returns the size of the string if it were rendered and constrained to
>   the specified size.
>
> `- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size`
>
> Parameters font The font to use for computing the string size. size
>   The maximum acceptable size for the string. This value is used to
>   calculate where line breaks and wrapping would occur. Return Value The
>   width and height of the resulting string’s bounding box.

Comment: It's excellent way. Thank you very much from me and users of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class method of the comment cell class that calculates the height of text needed for cell's height. Also create a class method that returns cell's default font, so you can always calculate proper cell height in cell's `layoutSubviews` and in UITableViewDelegate's `cellHeightForRowAtIndexPath` methods.

e.g.

```
+(UIFont *) defaultCommentFont {
    return [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:13];
}

+(CGSize) sizeOfComment:(NSString *)commentText maxWidth:(CGFloat)maxWidth {
    return [commentText sizeWithFont:[[self class] defaultCommentFont] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, MAX_FLOAT)];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    static CGFloat margin = <# margin #>;

    CGSize commentSize = [[self class] sizeOfComment:self.commentText maxWidth:self.contentView.frame.size.width - 2 * margin];

    self.commentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(margin, margin, commentSize.width, commentSize.height);
}
```

(*sorry if there are any mistakes in the code - using only the eye-based parser ;)*)

Having this, when you try to return a proper height of cell in UITableViewDelegate's method, you don't have to use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, because this, in some cases, can cause an uncontrolled recursion resulting in stack overflow.

And, like Till said, set the comment label's property `numberOfLines` to `0`.